# Seeded random plotting 2d grid

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

This has been bugging me for a few hours so I was wondering if anyone could help me out as I might be thinking about this the wrong way.

I want to be able to get a boolean value from a set of x and y coordinates on an grid with an infinite width and height. There are also other constraints, along the x axis there needs to be at least n places between two true values, I would also need to know the number of true values in the area from 0,0 to x,y.

The width and height of the area given to getTrueCoordinatesInArea is equal to x and y as its the area is created from 0,0 to x,y

If that makes sense..

So for example:

```
value = coordinateContainsTrue( x, y );//return true or false.
total = getTrueCoordinatesInArea( x , y );//Returns the total true values inside the area.
```

Edit: This would work off a seed.

Comment: That' correct, I've edited the question.

Comment: Almost sounds like you have 2 questions here - one to generate random points given some constraints and one to find the number of coordinates from a set of coordinates that lie within a specified area (starting at (0,0)). Does that sound about right? You kind of lost me at the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exacly what you need but I thought it sounded like a good and fun exercise. I hoped it's what you wanted. =) It's not coded exactly how I wanted. Would rather have used a bool[,] array but don't know how to make that one dynamic and didn't want to code my own class for this, but maybe I should have.

However, this solution should work.

```
private List<List<bool>> grid = new List<List<bool>>();

private int N = 4;

Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

private bool getRandomBoolean()
{
    return this.randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, 2) == 1;
}

private void testProgram()
{
    var containsTrue = coordinateContainsTrue(0, 10);
    var total = getTrueCoordinatesInArea(14, 2);
    var isTrue = coordinateIsTrue(15, 11);
}

private bool coordinateIsTrue(int x, int y)
{
    expandGridOfNeeded(x, y);

    return grid[x][y];
}

private bool coordinateContainsTrue(int x, int y)
{
    expandGridOfNeeded(x, y);

    for (int xTemp = 0; xTemp < x; xTemp++) // Loop columns
    {
        for (int yTemp = 0; yTemp < y; yTemp++) // Loop rows
        {
            if (grid[xTemp][yTemp])
                return true; // Return true if any true was found
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private int getTrueCoordinatesInArea(int x, int y)
{
    expandGridOfNeeded(x, y);

    var total = 0;

    for (int xTemp = 0; xTemp < x; xTemp++) // Loop columns
    {
        for (int yTemp = 0; yTemp < y; yTemp++) // Loop rows
        {
            if (grid[xTemp][yTemp])
                total++; // Increase count if true was found
        }
    }

    return total;
}

private void expandGridOfNeeded(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0)
        return;

    // Add needed columns
    while (grid.Count <= x)
    {
        var column = new List<bool>();

        // Only add rows if the others have rows
        if (grid.Count > 0)
        {
            while (column.Count < grid[0].Count)
            {
                // Check if legal to add a true value, if it is then add random else add false
                bool forceFalseValue = false;
                for (int i = grid.Count - 1; i > grid.Count + N && forceFalseValue == false; i--)
                {
                    forceFalseValue = grid[i][column.Count - 1];
                }

                column.Add(forceFalseValue ? false : getRandomBoolean());
            }
        }

        grid.Add(column);
    }

    // Add needed rows
    while (grid[0].Count <= y)
    {
        var counter = N;

        foreach (var column in grid)
        {
            // Check if legal to add a true value, if it is then add random else add false
            if (counter < N)
            {
                column.Add(false);
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                var randomValue = getRandomBoolean();

                if (randomValue)
                    counter = 0;
                else
                    counter++;

                column.Add(randomValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```